# Optimising busy website with Varnish and lots of ram

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, lamp, varnish

[Updated to be much more consise!]

I'm new to the world of optimising web servers for lots of traffic, but that's now something I'm getting into.

On Monday our webserver was 'slashdotted' - we got a massive surge of traffic (85,000 visitors in an hour or so) and even though we run Varnish and nginx (which are doing their job properly) the Apache side of things really struggled as there is some dynamic content that gets generated on some requests.

Server currently has 8GB of RAM, it's **being upgraded to 32GB very soon**, so really I need configuration help for a 32GB system. Currently running 64bit centos.

I've investigated the varnish and nginx setup, they're fine - sensible settings (static content dished out directly by nginx, lots of dynamic stuff dished out by varnish and if it's not in varnish the request is passed through to apache.)

So on to Apache.. we're using the MPM prefork module, each apache process seems to use up a LOT of ram:

Top 3:

```
S    48 20961  2965  0  75   0 187128 128307 ?    ?        00:05:25 httpd
S    48 20959  2965  0  75   0 249788 143435 ?    ?        00:05:55 httpd
S    48 18581  2965  0  75   0 314564 157747 ?    ?        00:06:40 httpd
```

Bottom 3:

```
S     0  2965     1  0  78   0 15132 89017 stext  ?        00:00:00 httpd
S    48 20947  2965  0  75   0 38492 93001 ?      ?        00:00:00 httpd
S    48 20945  2965  0  75   0 43300 93897 ?      ?        00:00:01 httpd
```

I'm not entirely sure, but I think that one process = one client = one connection to one persons browser. I guess my first question is can someone confirm that? Yes, we're running php and zend framework, MySQL as a database backend on the same server.

Current configuration (server is currently has 8GB ram):

```
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 2

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      200
MaxClients       200
MaxRequestsPerChild  500
</IfModule>
```

My thinking is currently Apache can theoretically try and use up about 63GB of ram in a worst case scenario with this configuration. Eg 315MB process * 200 maxclients = lots of ram. I'm not entirely sure it works like that, but if someone can confirm that too it'd help!

What I'd like to do is get some advice on what sort of things I should look out for - we want the server to be able to handle another surge of requests at any time and make use of all the new RAM we're getting. I'll get onto optimising MySQL in another question if I can't figure it out myself, but here's the conf just in case that makes a difference: http://pastebin.com/GbJU7AxY

Cheers a lot!
John.

Comment: Are most resources cacheable (and can be served completed by varnish without touching Apache) or do most resources need to be dynamically generated for each hit by PHP?  Maybe run `varnishhist` for a bit - that will give you a sense of how many hits are served from cache vs being sent to Apache.  What kind of TTL is varnish set up for?

Comment: That process list doesn't help much, without a header row. I've no idea which column is what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is that 85,000/day visitors number? Unique visitors, total HTTP hits, something else?

Varnish should be able to handle thousands of hits per second, with little CPU and memory, as long as the requests can be served from cache. Especially when Slashdotted, since most people will be looking for the exact same content. It does require finetuning though. It's quite conservative by default, since it doesn't know much about the content that passes through. It makes its descisions based on the headers it sees, and a simple ruleset. For example, by default Varnish caches objects for 2 minutes, but only if *no cookies* are present in the request, and the object's TTL is >0, and... etc. Check the default VCL (specifically *vcl_recv* and *vcl_fetch*) to determine the default logic, and make sure you understand it.

So, a single Google Analytics cookie set on your domain causes *all requests* to be passed to the backend, even though GA cookies are not process by your backend server but by Google's javascript. A WordPress application sets all kinds of cookies, most of which are only applicable to dynamic content, which get returned by the browser on every single request. If your page contains 49 static assets and 1 dynamic page, that means none of those static assets will be cached because the requests contain a cookie that you don't care about. Only the cookie on the dynamic request should get through. A mistake like that essentially disables Varnish. Also, the various cache-control (and related) HTTP headers that your code returns are important. If your application claims that the object that Varnish retrieves from the backend is already expired, for example with an Expires header in the past, Varnish will not cache that object.

In other words, you'll need to adjust your application to emit the correct headers, so the clients (both Varnish and the browser) are allowed to cache the returned content. Anything you can't correct in your application, you can override in Varnish's VCL.

For example, here is my code to remove various client-side tracking cookies from reaching the server. This belongs in `vcl_recv`:

```
# Remove tracking cookies. The server doesn't need to see them.
if (req.http.Cookie) {
    # Remove has_js and Google Analytics __* cookies.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js|sifrFetch)=[^;]*", "");
    # Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");
    # Remove cookie header if empty
    if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
        remove req.http.Cookie;
    }
}
```

Similarly I remove incoming cookies to certain paths, to make those requests cacheable:

```
if  ( req.url ~ "^/cms/cms_files/(?:css|img|js)/" ||  #CMS1
      req.url ~ "^/site_files/(?:css|img|imgc|js|swf|uploads|xml/.+\.xml$)" ||  #CMS1
      req.url ~ "^/(?:images|stylesheets|javascripts|swf|site_files/js_libs|site/image|favicon\.ico$|robots\.txt$)" ||  #CMS2
      ( req.http.host ~ "(?:shop\.example\.com|www\.example\.nl)"  &&  #Magento
        req.url ~  "^/(?:404|js|media|skin|favicon\.ico$)" ) || #Magento
) {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}
```

I use a similar stanza in vcl_fetch, with `unset beresp.http.cookie;` instead, to prevent the backend from setting any cookies on paths I don't want.

You could add some [debug headers](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleHitMissHeader) that give you info about how varnish processed requests. View those with Firebug, and you'll understand a lot more about your app. Another good source of information is the *Varnish Book*. For example, see: https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/VCL_Basics.html

Most of our dynamic content is cached for 60s, which is enough to fend off a stampede. If you require some individual content, but most of the content on your pages is quite static, look into Varnish's [ESI](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/esi.html) (edge-side-includes) which allows you to specify different cache-TTL's for different parts of the page.

Now that you've reduced the backend requests to the bare minimum, optimize those requests. Profile your application, find and fix problems.

You're correct that:
`MaxClients x (maximum physical memory per Apache process) = (total memory Apache can use)`

That's physical memory though, not the virtual memory that you mentioned. In top, the *res* column shows the physical memory used by each process. Each Apache process grows to the biggest scripts your site runs. Limit MaxClients to the amount your server can handle. It makes no sense to accept requests that you don't have the resources for. As soon as you start swapping, you've lost. Increase the amount of processes (Servers) that Apache preforks, since forking is a heavy operation that you want to do when it's already busy. The ServerLimit line is redundant. Either disable KeepAlive or set it to 1-2 seconds.

If you serve many static assets, consider switching from mod_php to PHP-FPM. This keeps your Apache processes light-weight.

Comment: Wow, thank you.. I'll need some time to digest and talk through this with my colleagues but that's really helpful!

Comment: By removing cookies on static content in `vcl_recv` - if you ever have a missing image/css/js file; the cookie will be stripped, the request redirected to the Magento bootstrap - and the subsequent customer session will be lost. This is A Bad Idea. Similarly, the max memory that Apache can use is the maximum PHP memory setting multiplied by number of children. Which if its a Magento store, is probably around 1GB ~= 200GB. The OP is probably massively over allocating on RAM. There isn't a use case for more than 2x CPU cores for Apache threads if its only handling dynamic content.

Comment: @sonassi You're right about the risk of losing sessions. This could be avoided by modifying the Magento .htaccess, but it's easy to make a mistake that way. Another solution could be to add the session cookie to the Varnish hash and strip the remaining cookies. This would reduce create a new cache per user, so reduce cache-consolidation, but is better than nothing. Any other advice?

Comment: @sonassi I agree that OP is likely over-allocating memory, which I failed to make clear. If I read his top output right, which is tricky without headers, he's using around 150MB max of physical RAM per process. With MaxClients set to 200 his Apache can consume around 30GB of RAM when all processes are running. More than available. Note that Apache's max memory is not just PHP's max memory, but includes all other mods and Apache itself, so you should always measure the actual max in the RES column when Apache has been running for a while.